# Specifying a Controller for a Directive to use on a specific page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**My question is whether specifying a Controller for a Directive per page (or wherever needed) is "allowed", not such a good idea, or whether there is perhaps a better way of doing thing?**

**Example:** Adding `ng-controller="SocialMentionsAnalysisController"` to my `og-social-mentions-social-media-nav` Directive, to make use of the functionality of that Controller. See below:

```
<og-social-mentions-social-media-nav ng-controller="SocialMentionsAnalysisController"></og-social-mentions-social-media-nav>
```

The reason for this is that I have been struggling to create an anchor scroll menu that will NOT reload my page.

I have tried a bunch of different possible solutions, when I came across the following method:

**1. Adding this Method in my Controller:**

```
  $scope.redirectTodiv = function(divname,event) {
     var id = $location.hash();
      $location.hash(divname);
      $anchorScroll();
      $location.hash(id);

   };
```

**2. Creating my menu links like this:**

```
<li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('top', $event)"><img title="Post List" src="images/postList.svg" title="" height="25" /><span class="navText">Summary</span></a></li>
<li><a href ng-click="redirectTodiv('mentionList', $event)"><img title="Mentions List" src="images/postList.svg" title="" height="25" /><span class="navText">Mentions List</span></a></li>
```

**3. And of course injecting `$location` and `$anchorScroll` in my Controller.**

This works great, but I struggled to make this work using my navigation Directive, until I specified the Controller in the Directive as explained above.

So, is this OK?

> **EDIT:** My Controller has minimal functionality. Here is my Controller
>   code:

```
angular.module('portalDashboardApp')
  .directive('ogSocialMentionsSocialMediaNav',['MenuState', function(MenuState) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: './socialMedia.module/socialMedia.templates/SocialMentionsSocialMediaNavTemplate.html',
      link: function(scope) {
        scope.getClass = MenuState.getClass;
      }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to solved this.

For Example, you have a directive menu:

```
myApp.directive('menu', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<nav class="nav">'+
'  <ul>'+
'    <li><a ui-sref="summary">Summary</a></li>'+
'    <li> <a ui-sref="mentions">Mentions</a></li>'+
'  </ul>'+
'</nav>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
            console.log("Run Menu");                       
        }
    };
});
```

in the root app add general config:

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ui.router", "AppCtrls1", "AppCtrls2"]);
    myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('root', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                "header@": {},
                "main@": {},
                "footer@": {}
            }
        });
     });
```

Finaly in the app's html:

```
<menu></menu> 
<div ui-view="main"></div>
```

#### Now you can create two apps:

The first app have a sub view `summary-level-2` in the same app, you also can inject other app into the sub view.

```
/** APP ONE **/
var subApp1 = angular.module("AppCtrls1", []);

subApp1.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state("summary", {
    parent:'root',
    views:{
       "main@":{
          controller: "Ctrl1",
              template: '<section class="red"><p>Summary</p> <div ui-view></div></section>'
       }
    },
    url: "/summary"
  })
  .state("summary-level-2", {
    parent:'summary',
    controller: "Ctrl2",
    template: '<p class="green">summary-level-2</p>',
    url: "/summary-level-2"
  });
});


subApp1.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope) {
  console.log("Ctrl1 loaded.");
});

subApp1.controller("Ctrl2", function($scope) {
  console.log("Ctrl2 loaded. level 2");
});


/** APP two **/
    var subApp2 = angular.module("AppCtrls2", []);
    subApp2.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
      .state("mentions", {
        parent:'root',
        views:{
           "main@":{
              controller: "Ctrl1",
                  template: "<p>Mentions</p>"
           }
        },
        url: "/mentions"
      });
    });

    subApp2.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope) {
      console.log("Ctrl1 loaded.");
    });
```

You can see a live example in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cob8vnmm/6/).

Comment: Thank you for the response! My problem is that I don't only have one menu. The app in totality has about 20 menus. Each page has it's own sub pages, and is responsible for its own routing. That is why I thought I could perhaps borrow from the Controller managing the view for each section. It seems to work. And as my actual directive has so little functionality, I don't think there will be any $scope clash.

Comment: Ok. can you add a diagram to see the page structure?